# Kaluza-Klein metric and Ricci scalar?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, gauge-theory, kaluza-klein

The metric is 
\begin{equation}
ds^2 = G^D_{MN}dx^M dx^N
= G_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu + G_{dd}(dx^d + A_\mu dx^\mu)^2.
\end{equation}
Then 
\begin{equation}
G^D = \begin{bmatrix}
G_{\mu\nu} + G_{dd}A_\mu A_\nu& G_{dd}A_\mu\\
G_{dd}A_\nu& G_{dd}
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}
In the above $G^D_{MN}$ is $D = d+1$ dimensional metric and $G_{\mu\nu}$ is $d$-dimensional metric.

How can I get the Ricci scalar 
\begin{equation}
R = R_d - 2e^{-\sigma}\nabla^2e^\sigma - \frac14e^{2\sigma}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}
\end{equation}
from the above metric?
Here $R_d$ is constructed from $G_{\mu\nu}$ and $R$ is constructed from $G^D_{MN}$ and $G_{dd} = e^{2\sigma}$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I think it's Kaluza--Klein compactification,

Comment: [This](http://www.weylmann.com/kaluza.pdf) might be helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [5D Ricci Curvature](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/64735/5d-ricci-curvature)

Comment: Nothing in *this* computation requires the extra dimension to be compact. It’s just an additional dimension.

Comment: Thank you! I think it's helpful

Comment: I would like to know how to find \alpha, \beta and \gamma in the second answer of this link. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/64735/5d-ricci-curvature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is essentially an elaboration of Prahar's answer in [5D Ricci Curvature](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/64735/5d-ricci-curvature) but with explicit details of how to determine the coefficients.

It is  an entirely straightforward albeit exceedingly tedious calculation.
Let us denote the $D$ dimensional quantities with a $\; \tilde{}\; $ and the $d$-dimensional quantities without one.
We start by looking at the mass-dimensions of the various quantities. These are $-1$ for $x^\mu, x^d, r $,      $0$ for     $\tilde G_{\mu\nu}, G_{\mu\nu}, A^\mu, \sigma$, and      $2$ for  $\tilde R, R, F_{\mu\nu}$.
The most general  combination of mass dimension two that we could use to expand $\tilde R$, keeping in mind that we have a $d$-dimensional diffeomorphism so that we should have scalars under that and also that  we have  a gauge symmetry, i.e. under $x^d\longrightarrow x^d + \lambda$ we have $A_\mu \longrightarrow A_\mu - \partial \lambda$, so that $A_\mu$ can only appear in gauge invariant combinations, is
$$
\tilde R =   a R + b F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu} + c (\nabla \sigma)^2 + d \sigma \nabla^2 \sigma + e\nabla^2 \sigma + f \tag{1}
$$
Here $a,b,c,d,e$ and $f$ are to be determined. They can depend on $\sigma$ as that is a scalar in $d$-dimensional space time, but they cannot depend on $G_{\mu\nu}$ or on $A_\mu$, as any such dependence is already in $R$ and $F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}$ respectively.

What else can we say? Under a scaling
\begin{align}
x^d \longrightarrow &\, \lambda x^d \nonumber\\
A_\mu \longrightarrow &\, \lambda A_\mu \nonumber\\
e^{2\sigma} \longrightarrow&\, \lambda^{-2} e^{2\sigma}  \label{eq:c8hgehkoe}
\end{align}
and keeping $x^\mu$ fixed, with $\lambda$ a constant,
the line element $ds^2 = G^d_{\mu\nu} dx^\mu dx^\nu + e^{2\sigma} (dx^d + A_\mu dx^\mu)^2$ is manifestly invariant. Under this scaling we obviously have
\begin{align}
F_{\mu\nu} F^{\mu\nu} \longrightarrow &\, \lambda^2 F_{\mu\nu} F^{\mu\nu} \nonumber\\
\nabla_\mu \sigma \longrightarrow&  \, \nabla_\mu \sigma 
\end{align}
The latter relation follows from $\sigma \longrightarrow \sigma - \ln \lambda$.
How does the curvature  scale under this? It turns out that $\tilde R$ remains unchanged under this scaling, and  so does $R$ as well.

This  is not too hard to see if we investigate the scaling of the metric components.  The metric is
\begin{align}
\tilde G_{\mu\nu} = &\,G_{\mu\nu} +e^{2\sigma} A_\mu A_\nu \nonumber\\
\tilde G_{\mu d} = &\,  e^{2\sigma} A_\mu  \nonumber\\
\tilde G_{dd} = &\,e^{2\sigma} 
\end{align}
The first think we notice is that
the determinant of the $D$ dimensional metric is very simply related to the determinant of the $d$ dimensional metric. One easily works out that
$$  \tilde G =  e^{2\sigma} \det G $$
The second observation is that the inverse of $\tilde G_{MN}$ is very simple
\begin{align}
\tilde G^{\mu\nu} = &\,G^{\mu\nu}  \nonumber\\
\tilde G^{\mu d} = &\,  -  A^\mu  \nonumber\\
\tilde G^{dd} = &\,e^{-2\sigma} + A_\mu A^\mu
\end{align}
Here $G^{\mu\nu}$ is the inverse of $G_{\mu\nu}$. It is easily checked that  $\tilde G_{MN} \tilde G^{NK} =\delta_M^K$.

From these expression of the metric we find the scaling
\begin{align}
\tilde G_{\mu\nu} \longrightarrow &\, \tilde G_{\mu\nu} \nonumber\\
\tilde G_{\mu d} \longrightarrow &\, \lambda \tilde G_{\mu d} \nonumber\\
\tilde G_{dd} \longrightarrow &\, \lambda^2\tilde G_{dd}  
\end{align}
and for the inverse metric
\begin{align}
\tilde G^{\mu\nu} \longrightarrow &\, \tilde G^{\mu\nu} \nonumber\\
\tilde G^{\mu d} \longrightarrow &\, \lambda^{-1} \tilde G^{\mu d} \nonumber\\
\tilde G^{dd} \longrightarrow &\, \lambda^{-2}\tilde G^{dd}  
\end{align}
We see that any upper index $^d$  gives a factor $\lambda$ and any lower index $_d$ gives a factor $\lambda^{-1}$. As the Ricci scalar is formed from the curvature tensor with all indices contracted and  any $^d$ can only contract with a $_d$ we conclude that $\tilde R$ indeed remains unchanged. $R$ is also unchanged as both $\tilde G_{\mu\nu}$ and $\tilde G^{\mu\nu}$ are invariant under our scaling.

Let us now go back to (1).
The LHS is invariant under our scaling. So the RHS must be invariant as well.  Recall that $a,b,c,d,e$ and $f$ are still allowed to be functions of $\sigma$, but as $R$ is invariant and $a(\sigma) R$ must also be invariant we need to have that $a$ is independent of $\sigma$. Similarly as $F_{\mu\nu} F^{\mu\nu}$ scales as $\lambda^2$, we must have that $b$ scales as $\lambda^{-2}$ and so $b\propto e^{2\sigma}$. Finally $\nabla \sigma$ is invariant, so $c,d$ and $e$ must be independent of $\sigma$.  We have thus established that
\begin{align}
 \tilde R =   \alpha R + \beta e^{2\sigma} F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu} + \gamma  (\nabla \sigma)^2 + \delta  \sigma \nabla^2 \sigma + \varepsilon \nabla^2 \sigma + f  \tag{2}
 \end{align}
for some constants $\alpha, \beta,\gamma, \delta$ and $\varepsilon$. We can still have $f$ to be a function of $\sigma$.

To fix the constants we need to work out the expression for $R$.This starts with getting the connections. The non-zero connections turn out to be
\begin{align}
\tilde \Gamma^\lambda_{\mu\nu}  =&\,  \Gamma^{\lambda}_{\mu\nu} -e^{2\sigma}\partial^\lambda \sigma A_\mu A_\nu + \frac{1}{2}e^{2\sigma} \big( A_\nu  F_{\mu}^{\;\;\lambda} + A_\mu  F_{\nu}^{\;\;\lambda} \big) \nonumber\\
\tilde \Gamma^\lambda_{\mu d} = & \, - e^{2\sigma} \partial^\lambda \sigma A_\mu + \frac{1}{2} e^{2\sigma}  F_{\mu}^{\;\;\lambda}  \nonumber\\
\tilde \Gamma^\lambda_{d d} = & \,  -e^{2\sigma} \partial^\lambda \sigma \nonumber\\
\tilde \Gamma^d_{\mu\nu}  =&\,\frac{1}{2} \Big(\nabla_\mu A_\nu + \nabla_\nu A_\mu\Big) + \frac{1}{2} e^{2\sigma}\Big( A^\rho A_\nu F_{\rho\mu} +A^\rho A_\mu F_{\rho\nu} \Big)\nonumber\\
& + \partial_\mu \sigma A_\nu + \partial_\nu\sigma A_\mu  +e^{2\sigma}A_\mu A_\nu A^\rho \partial_\rho \sigma \nonumber\\
\tilde \Gamma^d_{\mu d} = & \, \frac{1}{2} e^{2\sigma} A^\rho F_{\rho\mu} + e^{2\sigma} A_\mu A^\rho\partial_\rho \sigma +\partial_\mu\sigma \nonumber\\
\tilde \Gamma^d_{d d} = & \,  e^{2\sigma} A^\mu \partial_\mu \sigma 
\end{align}
If you have problems deriving this, let me know and I will give more details.

Let us set $A^\mu=\sigma=0$. In that case we simply have $\tilde R = R$ and so we find that $\alpha=1$.

Next, let us take $G_{\mu\nu}= \delta_{\mu\nu}$ and $A_\mu=0$, leaving only $\sigma$ free. The only non-vanishing metric component with upper indices and connections are then
\begin{align}
\tilde G^{\mu\nu} =&\,  \delta^{\mu\nu}  \nonumber\\
\tilde G^{dd} =&\, e^{-2\sigma} \nonumber\\ 
\tilde \Gamma^\mu_{dd} =&\, -e^{2\sigma} \partial^\mu \sigma\nonumber\\
\tilde \Gamma^d_{\mu d} =&\, \partial_\mu\sigma
\end{align}
The Ricci scalar thus reduces to
\begin{align}
\tilde R=&\,  \tilde G^{LM} \left( \partial_N \tilde \Gamma^N_{ML} -\partial_M \tilde \Gamma^N_{NL} +\tilde \Gamma^N_{NK}  \tilde \Gamma^K_{ML}  
-\tilde \Gamma^N_{MK}  \tilde \Gamma^K_{NL} \right) \tag{3} \\
=&\,
\tilde G^{\lambda\mu} \left( \partial_N \tilde \Gamma^N_{\mu\lambda} -\partial_\mu \tilde \Gamma^N_{N\lambda} +\tilde \Gamma^N_{NK}  \tilde \Gamma^K_{\mu\lambda}  
-\tilde \Gamma^N_{\mu K}  \tilde \Gamma^K_{N\lambda} \right) \nonumber\\
& + \tilde G^{dd} \left( \partial_N \tilde \Gamma^N_{dd} -\partial_d \tilde \Gamma^N_{Nd} +\tilde \Gamma^N_{NK}  \tilde \Gamma^K_{dd}  
-\tilde \Gamma^N_{dK}  \tilde \Gamma^K_{Nd} \right) \nonumber\\
=&\, \tilde G^{\lambda\mu} \left(-\partial_\mu \tilde \Gamma^d_{d\lambda}  -\tilde \Gamma^d_{\mu d}  \tilde \Gamma^d_{d\lambda} \right)  +\tilde G^{dd} \left( \partial_\nu \tilde \Gamma^\nu_{dd}  +\tilde \Gamma^d_{d\kappa}  \tilde \Gamma^\kappa_{dd}  
-\tilde \Gamma^\nu_{dd}  \tilde \Gamma^d_{\nu d} -\tilde \Gamma^d_{d\kappa}  \tilde \Gamma^\kappa_{dd} \right) \nonumber\\
=&\, -\partial_\mu \partial^\mu\sigma -\partial_\mu \sigma \partial^\mu \sigma +
e^{-2\sigma} \left[ \partial_\mu \left(-e^{2\sigma} \partial^\mu \sigma \right) - \partial_\mu \sigma \left(-e^{2\sigma} \partial^\mu \sigma\right)\right] \nonumber\\
=&\,   -\partial_\mu \partial^\mu\sigma -\partial_\mu \sigma \partial^\mu \sigma  -2\partial_\mu \sigma \partial^\mu \sigma -\partial_\mu \partial^\mu \sigma + \partial_\mu \sigma \partial^\mu \sigma \nonumber\\
=&\, -2( \partial_\mu \partial^\mu \sigma + \partial_\mu\sigma \partial^\mu\sigma)
\end{align}
From (2)  we have for this choice of metric
\begin{align}
\tilde R = \gamma (\partial \sigma)^2 + \delta \sigma\partial^2\sigma + \varepsilon \partial^2 \sigma + f
\end{align}
and we thus find that $\gamma=\varepsilon=-2$ and $\delta=f=0$. To link this to the expression in (8.1.8) note that
\begin{align}
e^{-\sigma} \partial^2 e^{\sigma} = &\, e^{-\sigma} \partial_\mu \Big( \partial_\mu \sigma e^\sigma \Big) = \partial_\mu\partial^\mu \sigma + \partial_\mu\sigma \partial^\mu \sigma
\end{align}
and $e^{-\sigma} \nabla^2 e^{\sigma}$ is just the covariant expression of this.

Finally, let us take $G_{\mu\nu}= \delta_{\mu\nu}$ and $\sigma=0$, leaving only the $A_\mu$ free. Here we don't have to do any calculations as the theory we have is just a Euclidean $d$ dimensional flat spacetime with an Abelian gauge field $A_\mu$ and we know that the action reduces to $-\frac{1}{4} F_{\mu\nu} F^{\mu\nu}$ so that $\beta =-\frac{1}{4}$.
Let us check this. The  only non-vanishing metric component with upper indices and connections are in this case
\begin{align}
\tilde G^{\mu\nu} =&\,  \delta^{\mu\nu}  \nonumber\\
\tilde G^{\mu d} = &\, -A^\mu  \nonumber\\
\tilde G^{dd} =&\, 1+ A_\mu A^\mu  \nonumber\\ 
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\tilde \Gamma^\lambda_{\mu\nu}  =&\,  \frac{1}{2} \big( A_\nu  F_{\mu}^{\;\;\lambda} + A_\mu  F_{\nu}^{\;\;\lambda} \big) \nonumber\\
\tilde \Gamma^\lambda_{\mu d} = & \, \frac{1}{2}   F_{\mu}^{\;\;\lambda}  \nonumber\\
\tilde \Gamma^d_{\mu\nu}  =&\,\frac{1}{2} \Big(\partial_\mu A_\nu + \partial_\nu A_\mu\Big) + \frac{1}{2} \Big( A^\rho A_\nu F_{\rho\mu} +A^\rho A_\mu F_{\rho\nu} \Big)\nonumber\\
\tilde \Gamma^d_{\mu d} = & \, \frac{1}{2}  A^\rho F_{\rho\mu}  
\end{align}
Let us do the four terms of the Ricci scalar (3) separately. Because $G_{\mu\nu} =\delta_{\mu\nu}$ we do not have to make a distinction between upper and lower indices in $d$-spacetime and will move them all downstairs, but we do need to be careful with the order. We start with
\begin{align}
\tilde G^{LM}  \partial_N \tilde \Gamma^N_{ML} =&\,\tilde G^{LM}  \partial_\nu \tilde \Gamma^\nu_{ML} = \tilde G^{\lambda M}  \partial_\nu \tilde \Gamma^\nu_{M\lambda} +\tilde G^{dM}  \partial_\nu \tilde \Gamma^\nu_{Md} \nonumber\\
=&\,\tilde G^{\lambda \mu}  \partial_\nu \tilde \Gamma^\nu_{\mu\lambda}  + \tilde G^{\lambda d}  \partial_\nu \tilde \Gamma^\nu_{d\lambda} +
\tilde G^{d\mu}  \partial_\nu \tilde \Gamma^\nu_{\mu d}+\tilde G^{dd}  \partial_\nu \tilde \Gamma^\nu_{dd} \nonumber\\
=&\, \frac{1}{2}\delta_{\lambda \mu} \partial_\nu \big( A_\mu F_{\lambda\nu} + A_\lambda F_{\mu \nu} \big) -\frac{1}{2} A_\lambda \partial_\nu F_{\lambda \nu}  -\frac{1}{2} A_\mu \partial_\nu F_{\mu \nu} \nonumber\\
=&\, \frac{1}{2} \Big( \partial_\nu A_\mu F_{\mu\nu} +A_\mu \partial_\nu  F_{\mu\nu}  +\partial_\nu A_\mu F_{\mu\nu} +  A_\mu \partial_\nu F_{\mu\nu} - A_\mu \partial_\nu F_{\mu \nu}  - A_\mu \partial_\nu F_{\mu \nu}  \Big) \nonumber\\
=&\, \partial_\nu A_\mu F_{\mu\nu} = \frac{1}{2}  F_{\mu\nu}(\partial_\nu A_\mu -\partial_\mu A_\nu)  = -\frac{1}{2} F_{\mu\nu} F_{\mu\nu}
\end{align}
where in the last line we have antisymmetrised the result.
Next we have
\begin{align}
- \tilde G^{LM}  \partial_M \tilde \Gamma^N_{NL} =&\,- \tilde G^{L\mu}  \partial_\mu \tilde \Gamma^N_{NL}  = - \tilde G^{L\mu}  \partial_\mu \tilde \Gamma^\nu_{\nu L}- \tilde G^{L\mu}  \partial_\mu \tilde \Gamma^d_{dL} \nonumber\\
=&\, - \tilde G^{\lambda\mu}  \partial_\mu \tilde \Gamma^\nu_{\nu \lambda }- \tilde G^{d\mu}  \partial_\mu \tilde \Gamma^\nu_{\nu d }- \tilde G^{\lambda\mu}  \partial_\mu \tilde \Gamma^d_{d\lambda} - \tilde G^{d\mu}  \partial_\mu \tilde \Gamma^d_{dd} \nonumber\\
=&\, -\frac{1}{2} \delta_{\lambda\mu} \partial_\mu\big(A_\nu F_{\lambda\nu} + A\lambda F_{\nu\nu}\big) +\frac{1}{2} A_\mu \partial_\mu F_{\nu\nu} 
-\frac{1}{2} \delta_{\lambda\mu}\partial_\mu \big(A^\rho F_{\rho \lambda} \big)\nonumber\\
=&\, \frac{1}{2} \Big( -\partial_\mu A_\nu F_{\mu\nu} - A_\nu \partial_\mu  F_{\mu\nu} -\partial_\mu A_\rho F_{\rho\mu} - A_\rho \partial_\mu F_{\rho\mu} \Big) =0
\end{align}
The third and fourth terms with the products of the connections are a bit more work albeit straightforward. The result is
\begin{align}
\tilde G^{LM} \tilde \Gamma^N_{NK}  \tilde \Gamma^K_{ML}   = &\,0 \nonumber\\
-\tilde G^{LM} \tilde \Gamma^N_{MK}  \tilde \Gamma^K_{NL} =&\, \frac{1}{4} F_{\mu\nu} F_{\mu\nu}
\end{align}
Bringing the four terms together we conclude that
\begin{align}
\tilde R =  -\frac{1}{2} F_{\mu\nu} F_{\mu\nu}+  \frac{1}{4} F_{\mu\nu} F_{\mu\nu} =  -\frac{1}{4} F_{\mu\nu} F_{\mu\nu}
\end{align}
and hence $\beta=-1/4$.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Under the rescaling why does $\tilde G_{dd}  = e^{2\sigma}$ changes as
$\tilde G_{dd} = \lambda^2G_{dd}$?

Comment: I still have one more question.
I tried to get the same result by culculating spin connections
https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/555797/190058

Comment: Just write out the matrix and play with combining columns: it is freshman algebra. I haven’t done the spin connection calculation, so can’t help you there. If you agree with the answer can you accept it?

Comment: Thanks! You helped me a lot!

Comment: @KoKo pls accept the answer then.

Comment: how? I still don't understand how to use this site...