# Spin connection, curvature

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, quantum-spin, curvature, kaluza-klein

The metric is ($a,b, = 0,1,2,3,4$)
\begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
ds^2 = g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu + e^{2\sigma}(dx^4 + A_\mu dx^\mu)^2
= \eta_{ab}e^ae^b + (e^4)^2.
\end{equation}

The vielbeins are
$e^a = {e^a}_\mu dx^\mu$ and
$e^4 = e^\sigma(dx^4 + A_\mu dx^\mu)$.
The spin connection is defined as
$de^I = -\varOmega^I_{\;\;J}e^J$.
We can calculate the spin connection
\begin{equation}
\varOmega^a_{\;\;b} 
= \Omega^a_{\;\;b} - \frac12e^\sigma F^a_{\;\;b}e^4,\;\;
\varOmega^4_{\;\;a}
= \frac12e^\sigma F_{ab}e^b + \partial_a\sigma e^4,
\end{equation}
where $\varOmega^a_{\:\:b}$ is five dimensional spin connection and $\Omega^a_{\:\:b}$ is the four dimensional one.

The curvature is, first for components without 4th dimensional index,
(for simplicity we omit $\wedge$ in the following calculation)
\begin{align*}
\mathcal R^a_{\;\;b}
&= d\varOmega^a_{\;\;b} + \varOmega^a_{\;\;M}\wedge\varOmega^M_{\;\;b} 
= d\varOmega^a_{\;\;b} + \varOmega^a_{\;\;c}\wedge\varOmega^c_{\;\;b}
 + \varOmega^a_{\;\;4}\wedge\varOmega^4_{\;\;b}\\
&= d\Omega^a_{\;\;b} 
 - \frac12e^\sigma\partial_c\sigma F^a_{\;\;b}e^ce^4
 - \frac12e^\sigma\partial_cF^a_{\;\;b}e^ce^4
 + \frac12e^\sigma F^a_{\;\;b}
  \Big(\frac12e^\sigma F_{cf}e^f + \partial_c\sigma e^4\Big)e^c\\
&\quad
 + \Big(\Omega^a_{\;\;c} - \frac12e^\sigma F^a_{\;\;c}e^4\Big)
  \Big(\Omega^c_{\;\;b} - \frac12e^\sigma F^c_{\;\;b}e^4\Big) 
 - \Big(\frac12e^\sigma F^a_{\;\;c}e^c + \partial^a\sigma e^4\Big)
  \Big(\frac12e^\sigma F_{bf}e^f + \partial_b\sigma e^4\Big).
\end{align*}
The 4-dimensional part gives $R^a_{\;\;b}$ (4-dimensional curvature) and the remaining terms are
\begin{align*}
&-\frac12e^\sigma\partial_c\sigma F^a_{\;\;b}e^ce^4
 - \frac12e^\sigma\partial_cF^a_{\;\;b}e^ce^4
 - \frac14e^{2\sigma}F^a_{\;\;b}F_{cd}e^ce^d
 - \frac12e^\sigma\partial_c\sigma F^a_{\;\;b}e^ce^4\\
&\quad
 - \frac12e^\sigma\Omega^a_{\;c}F^c_{\;\;b}e^4
 + \frac12e^\sigma F^a_{\;c}\Omega^c_{\;\;b}e^4
 - \frac14e^{2\sigma}F^a_{\;\;c}F_{bd}e^ce^d  
 - \frac12e^\sigma\partial_b\sigma F^a_{\;\;c}e^ce^4
 + \frac12e^\sigma\partial^a\sigma F_{bc}e^ce^4.
\end{align*}
The components including one 4th dimensional index are
\begin{align*}
\mathcal R^a_{\;\;4}
&= d\varOmega^a_{\;\;4} + \varOmega^a_{\;\;c}\wedge\varOmega^c_{\;\;4}\\
&= -\frac12e^\sigma\partial_c\sigma F^a_{\;\;b}e^ce^b
 - \frac12e^\sigma\partial_cF^a_{\;\;b}e^ce^b
 + \frac12e^\sigma F^a_{\;\;b}
  \Big(\Omega^b_{\;\;c} - \frac12e^\sigma F^b_{\;\;c}e^4\Big)e^c
 - \partial_b\partial^a\sigma e^be^4
 - \partial^a\sigma
  \Big(-\frac12e^\sigma F_{dc}e^c - \partial_d\sigma e^4\Big)e^d\\
&\quad
 + \Big(\Omega^a_{\;\;c} - \frac12e^\sigma F^a_{\;\;c}e^4\Big)
  \Big(-\frac12e^\sigma F^c_{\;\;b}e^b - \partial^c\sigma e^4\Big)\\
&= -\frac12e^\sigma\partial_b\sigma F^a_{\;\;c}e^be^c
 - \frac12e^\sigma\partial_bF^a_{\;\;c}e^be^c
 + \frac12e^\sigma
  (F^a_{\;\;c}\Omega^c_{\;\;b} - \Omega^a_{\;\;c}F^c_{\;\;b})e^b
 - \partial^a\partial_b\sigma e^be^4\\
&\quad
 - \frac12e^\sigma\partial^a\sigma F_{cd}e^ce^d
 - \partial^a\sigma\partial_b\sigma e^be^4
 - \Omega^a_{\;\;c}\partial^c\sigma e^4
 - \frac14e^{2\sigma}F^a_{\;\;c}F^c_{\;\;b}e^be^4.
\label{eq:R441}
\end{align*}

The components of the Riemann curvature tensor are
\begin{equation}
\mathcal R^a_{\;\;b} 
= \frac12\mathcal R^a_{bcd}e^c\wedge e^d + \mathcal R^a_{bc4}e^c\wedge e^4,
\;\;
\mathcal R^a_{\;\;4} 
= \frac12\mathcal R^a_{4cd}e^c\wedge e^d + \mathcal R^a_{4c4}e^c\wedge e^4.
\end{equation}
We need $\mathcal R_{ab} = \mathcal R^c_{acb}$ and
$\mathcal R_{44} = \mathcal R^c_{4c4}$.
From the calculation of $\mathcal R^a_{\;\;b}$ the coefficient of $e^b\wedge e^c$ can be read as
\begin{align*}
\mathcal R^a_{\;\;b}
&= R^a_{\;\;b} 
 - \frac14e^{2\sigma}(F^a_{\;\;b}F_{cd} + F^a_{\;\;c}F_{bd})e^c\wedge e^d
 + (\cdots)_{c4}e^c\wedge e^4
=: \frac12\mathcal R^a_{bcd}e^c\wedge e^d + (\cdots)_{c4}e^c\wedge e^4,\\
\mathcal R^a_{bcd}
&= R^a_{bcd} - \frac12e^{2\sigma}(F^a_{\;\;b}F_{cd} + F^a_{\;\;c}F_{bd}).
\end{align*}
For $\mathcal R^a_{\;\;4}$, the component $\mathcal R^a_{4b4}$ is
\begin{equation*}
\mathcal R^a_{4b4}
= - \partial^a\partial_b\sigma 
 - \partial^a\sigma\partial_b\sigma
 - \frac14e^{2\sigma}F^a_{\;\;c}F^c_{\;\;b}
= \eta^{ac}R^4_{c4b}.
\end{equation*}
Then we found
\begin{equation}
\mathcal R^c_{acb}
= R^c_{acb} 
 - \frac12e^{2\sigma}F^c_{\;\;a}F_{cb},\;\;
\mathcal R^a_{4b4}
= -\partial^a\partial_b\sigma 
 - \partial^a\sigma\partial_b\sigma
 + \frac14e^{2\sigma}F^{ab}F_{ab}
= \eta^{ac}\mathcal R^4_{c4b}.
\end{equation}
By taking the contraction,
\begin{equation}
\mathcal R_{ab} = \mathcal R^M_{aMb}
= R^c_{acb} - \partial_a\partial_b\sigma 
 - \partial_a\sigma\partial_b\sigma
 - \frac12e^{2\sigma}F^c_{\;\;a}F_{cb},\;\;
\mathcal R_{44}
= -\partial^a\partial_a\sigma 
 - \partial^a\sigma\partial_a\sigma
 + \frac14e^{2\sigma}F^{ab}F_{ab}.
\end{equation}
By taking the contract again,
\begin{equation}
\mathcal R 
:= \eta^{ab}\mathcal R_{ab}
 + \mathcal R_{44}
= R - 2e^{-\sigma}\partial^a(\partial_a\sigma e^{\sigma})
 - \frac14e^{2\sigma}F^{ab}F_{ab}
= R - 2e^{-\sigma}\nabla^2e^{\sigma}
 - \frac14e^{2\sigma}F^{ab}F_{ab}. 
\end{equation}

My question is the following.
When I find the component of $R^a_{4b4}$, I picked the coefficient of $e^b\wedge e^4$.
But I think the term $- \Omega^a_{\;\;c}\partial^c\sigma e^4\propto e^b\wedge e^4$ must be took into account.
Then, is this derivation wrong?

Comment: It seems that these additional connections terms you are asking about combine with the partial derivative terms of the field strength to form covariant derivatives. If you compute the mixed (a4) component of the Ricci tensor (which you don't), then there should be covariant derivatives.

Comment: @Tim Thanks your comment (^^)v